# ".geometry("LxH")" and ".minsize(L,H)" doesn't give right size of window when compiled

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a user interface for my program and I'm facing some problem using a code I've just paste. The problem is that when i run my program the size of the window is shrinked to the minimum, but not the minsize minimum but the very minimum just to show the text. And another problem is that the title i enter isn't the title that appears in the tkinter window that is created.

```py
from tkinter import *

Interface = Tk() #creation of the first window
Interface.title = ("A very fancy title") #name of the window
Interface.geometry =("1080 x 720 +0 + 0") #window size
Interface.minsize=(720,480) #minimum window sizes
Interface.config(background = 'black')

title_frame = Frame(Interface, bg = 'black', bd = 1, relief = SUNKEN)
first_title = Label(title_frame, text="A title", font=("Arial",30) ,bg='black', fg='white')
first_title.pack()

second_title = Label(title_frame, text="a subtitle", font=("Arial",15) ,bg='black', fg='white')
second_title.pack()

var_texte = StringVar()
ligne_texte = Entry(title_frame, textvariable=var_texte, width=30)
ligne_texte.pack()

title_frame.pack(anchor=NW)

title_frame_2 = Frame(Interface, bg = 'black', bd = 1, relief = SUNKEN)
first_title_2 = Label(title_frame_2, text="A second title", font=("Arial",30) ,bg='black', fg='white')
first_title_2.pack()
title_frame_2.pack(anchor=SE)

Interface.mainloop()
```

The expected output would be a window named "A fancy title" with a black background. A text "A title" and "a subtitle" in the North West corner and "A second title" in  the South East corner. All that with a window size of 1080x720.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the methods with parameters as follows: (**Do not assign them**)

```
Interface.title("A very fancy title") #name of the window
Interface.geometry("1080x720+0+0") #window size **no gaps between the dimensions**
Interface.minsize(720,480) #minimum window sizes
```